# How to access Symfony Components in a custom main file

Tags: php, symfony, batch-file, symfony-2.6

I am working to make a batch file which will get some data from DB and send email. A folder `Batch` is created in the same level of `app and web`. Now my question is - how to access DB and other controls out of controller.

I tried to import 
`use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;` but it gives error saying no such files found.

I don;t want it to be command/console app.

My aim is to create a file which uses symfony components and Doctrine by staying outside bundle/controller. How do I import files in the file?.

Comment: Tried to use command? In command you con get doctrine via container. Like inside a controller.

Comment: I tried it. it is giving me a weird error - `Notice: Use of undefined constant OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS - assumed 'OCI_COMM
IT_ON_SUCCESS'` but it is working fine when used in web.

Comment: Define your class as a service and inject the needed dependencies?

Comment: @ManojKumar did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

First I really recommend to create a [Symfony Console Command](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/console/console_command.html) for this.

But if you really want to create a file (lets say `test.php`) in your document root, you can load a symfony service like this:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/app/autoload.php'; // load the autoloader

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false); // create a kernel instance
$kernel->loadClassCache(); // load the class cache
$kernel->boot(); // boot the kernel which will initialise the container.

$myInstance = $kernel->getContainer()->get('myservice');

$myInstance->doWhatever();
```

*PS: In there you should also be able to make use of all other symfony components.*

PPS: The `Notice: Use of undefined constant OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS - assumed 'OCI_COMM IT_ON_SUCCESS'` error tells you that something is wrong with your `oci8` extension try to reinstall/install or enable it again. http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php

Comment: I am able to come near to the issue - for console application it is using different `php.ini` file I got it through `php -i | find "Configuration file`. I have multiple instances of Xampp and it is referring one which I am not using.